# Statistics on discrete probability with error?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, error-propagation

I need help with this question, am pretty confused on what to do with the error, I can't see how to use it.

[image]

Comment: For example, in a. you need to consider simply two options: That one was produced and transmitted without error, or that 0 was produced and transmitted with error. These are the only possibilities for observing 1 at the outpot.

Comment: how do u compute the one transmitted with error, because u can't juts add on 0.2 b's it could be the other bit

Comment: The probability that 1 was transmitted is 0.7. The probability no error accured is 0.2. Considering the fact we are working in probability space where these are independent, we have the probability of 1 being transmitted with no error at 0.7*0.2. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Have you considered Bayes' Theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(a)** 1 can be observed at the output if: 
(i) 1 is produced at the source and transmitted correctly OR
(ii) 0 is produced at the source and is transmitted incorrectly.

So, Pr[1 at target] = Pr[1 at source]*Pr[transmitted correctly] + Pr[0 at source]*Pr[transmitted incorrectly]

i.e Pr[1 at target] = 0.7*(1-0.2) + 0.3*0.2
                    = 0.56 + 0.06
                    = 0.62

**(b)** Straightforward use of Bayes theorem.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.